# How to create a relation that is symmetric and antisymmetric.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to prove that if the relation $R$ is symmetric and anti-symmetric, then $R$ is transitive with the non empty set $A$.

I wanted to do an example to see how this proposition is true.
I just want to know if my relation of ordered pairs is actually symmetric and anti-symmetric:

Let $A$ = $\{1,2,3\}$

$R$ = $\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)\}$

Comment: Your relation is not antisymmetric: it includes both $\langle 1,3\rangle$ and $\langle 3,1\rangle$, so you have $1\,R\,3$ and $3\,R\,1$ without having $1=3$.

Comment: So in order for R to be anti-symmetric, I have to take those pairs out?

Comment: @Mark: those and others

Comment: @Mark: Only three of the ordered pairs that you used can belong to a relation that is both symmetric and antisymmetric.

Comment: Then it has to be (1,1),(2,2) and (3,3) because they fit the definitions of anti-symmetric and symmetric relations.

Comment: Unless there is something I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relation is not antisymmetric: it includes both $\langle 1,3\rangle$ and $\langle 3,1\rangle$, so you have $1\,R\,3$ and $3\,R\,1$ without having $1=3$.

It will help to figure out a bit more about what $R$ can be.

Suppose that $R$ is a symmetric, antisymmetric relation on $A$, $x,y\in A$, and $x\ne y$. Since $R$ is symmetric, if it contains one of the pairs $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\langle y,x\rangle$, it must contain both. In other words, it can contain both or neither, but it cannot contain just one of the two pairs. On the other hand, since $R$ is antisymmetric, it cannot contain both pairs: remember, an antisymmetric relation can contain both $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\langle y,x\rangle$ only when $x=y$. Thus, $R$ must contain neither of the pairs $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\langle y,x\rangle$ when $x\ne y$.

What kinds of ordered pairs **can** belong to $R$?

Comment: I can understand how I get the three ordered pairs remaining. But I don't understand how they are transitive. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @Mark: Actually you get **at most** those three remaining: $\{\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 3,3\rangle\}$, for instance, is also a symmetric, antisymmetric relation on $A$. For transitivity just check the definition. Suppose that $x,y,z\in A$, $x\,R\,y$, and $y\,R\,z$. Then $x=y$; why? Can you see now why $x\,R\,z$?

Comment: @user4140: I was trying to nudge Mark in the right direction.

Comment: Oh, sometimes I forget pedagogy, i get excited when I'm doing math sometimes.

Comment: I understand that when you have $\{(1,1),(3,3)\}$ it can be symmetric and antisymmetric relation. But I still don't see how its transitive. 

Where do you get $z$ in the relation? I know you got $x$ from 1 or 3 and $y$ from 1 or 3. Therefore you have $x=y$ but where does that $z$ come from?

Comment: @Mark: The definition of transitivity simply says that if $x\,R\,y$ and $y\,R\,z$, then we must also have $x\,R\,z$. It says nothing about whether $x,y$, and $z$ are distinct: they can be three different elements of $A$, or two of them can be the same and different from the third, or all three of them can be the same. All that’s required is that whenever $x,y,z\in A$, $x\,R\,y$, and $y\,R\,z$, then $x\,R\,z$. And for this relation that’s the case: you only ever get $x\,R\,y$, and $y\,R\,z$ when $x=y=z$, and in that case $x\,R\,z$, because $x\,R\,y$, and $y=z$.

Comment: So would (1,1) be (x,y) and (3,3) be (y,z)?

Comment: @Mark: No: you can’t have $y$ trying to be two different things at the same time. If $R=\{\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 3,3\rangle\}$, the only possible instances of transitivity are $1\,R\,1$ and $1\,R\,1$, with $x=y=1$ and $y=z=1$, and $3\,R\,3$ and $3\,R\,3$, with $x=y=3$ and $y=z=3$. And in both cases it’s true that $x\,R\,z$: in the first case $x=z=1$, and it’s true that $1\,R\,1$, and in the second case $x=z=3$, and it’s true that $3\,R\,3$.

Comment: @Mark: In principle each of $x,y$, and $z$ can be any member of $A$. However, the definition of transitivity actually imposes a requirement on $R$ only when it happens to be the case that $x\,R\,y$ and $y\,R\,z$. Out of all of the $3^3=27$ possible choices for $x,y$, and $z$ when $A=\{1,2,3\}$, only two actually meet that condition, namely, the two that I described in my last comment. In those two cases it does turn out that $x\,R\,z$, and they’re the only relevant cases, so $R$ is transitive.

Comment: Ok so for the first ordered pair (1,1) I understand that x=y=1 but I don't get how y=z=1.

Comment: @Mark: Because if $y=1$, and $y\,R\,z$, then $z=1$: the **only** ordered pair in $R$ that has $1$ as first component is $\langle 1,1\rangle$, so if $1\,R\,z$, then $z$ must be $1$.

Comment: Got it. So the same applies for (3,3) therefore the relation is transitive.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, that’s right. And more or less the same thing happens with any symmetric, antisymmetric relation on any set.

Comment: Awesome, I think you just helped me pass my final. Thanks Brian.

Comment: @Mark: I hope so. You’re welcome!

Comment: Just one last question, why can't we have (2,2) in the relation. Wouldn't that pair fit the definition of being transitive as well?

Comment: @Mark: We can. Any subset of the equality (or identity) relation on $A$, which is $$\{\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 2,3\rangle,\langle 3,3\rangle\}\;,$$ is both symmetric and antisymmetric, and is transitive for the same general reason.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a relation $R$ over $A$x$B$ with $(a,b)\in R$. Then because of symmetry we have $(b,a)\in R$ but because of antisymmetry we have  $(a=b)$ Therefore a relationship is both symmetric and antisymmetric if and only if $R\subseteq (A\cap B)^2$ but then the only transitive arguments we could have is $(a,a)$ therefore $(a,a)$ therefore $(a,a)$ which would in fact always be true. Therefore it is transitive.